# Java Script error handling

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I check my two (or one) input fileds if they are empty i want to let's say print alert in window but if they have vaules i want to run **else** but in my case alert is not popping up and if i want to submit those two fileds with data it is ok pushing it and doing alll stuff in **else** but whole browser is reloading. I was trying to add prevent.Default() but not working. Or return false

**UPDATE:** I made some changes and know when input is empty alert is popping up, but when i colse it it is still realoding whole page, same thing if else is executed all browser is reloading

```
 let pushBtn = document.getElementById('push-btn');

pushBtn.addEventListener('click', pushData);


 function pushData() {

let deviceVal = document.getElementById('device').value;
let powerVal = document.getElementById('power').value;

if (deviceVal != '' || powerVal != '') {
    let list = document.getElementById('list-group')
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    let liFirst = document.createElement('li');
    let liSecond = document.createElement('li');
    let liThird = document.createElement('li');

    button.classList.add("list-group-item");
    ul.classList.add("desc");
    liFirst.classList.add("t-desc");
    liSecond.classList.add("t-desc2");
    liThird.classList.add("t-desc3");
    liFirst.textContent = deviceVal;
    liSecond.textContent = powerVal;
    liThird.innerHTML = `<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>`
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    ul.append(liFirst);
    ul.append(liSecond);
    ul.append(liThird);
    button.append(ul);

    list.prepend(button);



} else {
    alert('aaa');
    return false

}
```

}

Comment: You have mixed jQuery methods (`append`, `prepend`) with native elements.

Comment: open browser's inspector panel, got to console tab and see errors (if they will appear)

Comment: no error's in console

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="device" required />
```

Job done, no JavaScript needed.

<sup>* But you should use a `submit` event on the form, not a `click` event on the button.</sup>

---

Specifically for your question, you want the alert to trigger if either input *is* blank, but you're testing if either one *isn't* blank. Use `==` instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can log to console before the "if" statement and inspect deviceVal/powerVal values, or use `built-in debbuger` in browser.

```
function pushData() {

   console.log(deviceVal)
   console.log(powerVal)

   if (deviceVal != '' || powerVal != '') {
      alert('aaa');
   } else {..}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok got it!

```
function pushData(e) {

let deviceVal = document.getElementById('device').value;
let powerVal = document.getElementById('power').value;
e.preventDefault()
if (deviceVal != '' || powerVal != '') {
    let list = document.getElementById('list-group')
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    let liFirst = document.createElement('li');
    let liSecond = document.createElement('li');
    let liThird = document.createElement('li');

    button.classList.add("list-group-item");
    ul.classList.add("desc");
    liFirst.classList.add("t-desc");
    liSecond.classList.add("t-desc2");
    liThird.classList.add("t-desc3");
    liFirst.textContent = deviceVal;
    liSecond.textContent = powerVal;
    liThird.innerHTML = `<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>`
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    ul.append(liFirst);
    ul.append(liSecond);
    ul.append(liThird);
    button.append(ul);

    list.prepend(button);



} else {
    alert('aaa');


}
```

}